# Failed to transform file 'library-1.2.0.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=processed-aar} using transform JetifyTransform

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetifier

I am migrating my existing project to Androidx . After adding this 2 line

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in `gradle.properties` , I get a bunch of compile error . I found many solution but nothing worked for me . Please help me out.Thanks

gradle(app-level)

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.faridabadtaxirider"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
    //Add library

    implementation 'com.github.aarsy.googlemapsanimations:googlemapsanimations:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.29.0'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'//Fix crash account kit
    implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:1.1@aar'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.2.0'` is not compatible with AndroidX. Try to use the latest version of that lib.